# Import Multiple Events to Android Calendar

Tags: android, icalendar, vcalendar

I am trying to use PHP to export a bunch of events to a file that can be imported to the Android calendar app.  I have tried an iCalendar (ICS) file, but Android can't read that.  vCalendar (VCS) doesn't allow you to have multiple events (according to RFC2445), so the app just crashes if you add multiple events.

Is there any way I can export multiple events to a file that can be imported to the Android calendar app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specialized app like CalendarSync to import ics files. I do this multiple times a week using that app and it works fine.[CalendarSync Link](http://ntbab.dyndns.org/apache2-default/seite/icalparseandroid.html)